# Java GUI application is hanging when the background script is running for a lot of time

Tags: java, user-interface

I am developing a Java application in which am using `GUI frames` using SWING I.E swing.jframe
in the frame we give some inputs for the application.

the application will take inputs and executes java code. the code will run for almost 2 - 3 hrs.

The problem occurs when I create a `runnable` jar for that application. When I run that jar after giving inputs and initating the script the GUI screen of my application is appearing as a black screen. Nothing is visible.

I want the screen visible even while running the script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you run the script in its own thread?

Comment: I haven't used any threads concept in my application

Comment: => must read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: @assylias This assumes that OP uses swing for GUI...

Comment: I would assume that by "run script" OP doesn't mean "run Java code", but starting a native subprocess.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ..but it is being launched from the Java code anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @SargeBorsch Probably yes. But you can launch a process such that it doesn't require any threads to supervise it.

Comment: I need not provide any values when the script is running. but the screen should be visible enough for that should i use multi threading concept??????????

Comment: @user2572003 You need to provide more information: what UI environment are you using (Swing?), how do you run your "script" (is it java code)?

Comment: i have actually created some JFrames and the script is java code . when we give inputs from UI frame and press the button then the java code will run

Answer (score 3):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //run yout script here
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: If you're using swt for your gui and need to update it while the script is running (e.g. showing a progress) then use Display.asynchExec method within your new Thread as described above

Comment: actually i need not update anything but the screen should be visible while the background script is running

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). It will help resolve the problem of *freezes* from long running tasks. If you run the program from the EDT and have the background task running on the *worker thread* , it should help with your problem.

See the entire [Concurrency with Swing tutorial trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)